# Data Split in R based on Row Relationship Values

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, reshape, tidyr

My Dataframe has the following structure:

| Start Value | Middle Value(s) | Final Value | Relationship |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | lowers, lowers |
| A | D, E | C | lowers, raises, raises |

I am trying to format the data so that I end up with:

| Start Value | Relationship | Final Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | lowers | B |
| B | lowers | C |
| A | lowers | D |
| D | raises | E |
| E | raises | C |

I have been struggling to format my data like this. At first I tried tidyr separate_rows() and some form of melting the data with reshape2 and data.table, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We could `unite` the columns and then split the column with `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  unite(StartValue, StartValue, MiddleValue, sep=", ", remove = FALSE) %>%
  unite(FinalValue, MiddleValue, FinalValue, sep=", ") %>% 
  separate_rows(c(StartValue, FinalValue, Relationship))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  StartValue FinalValue Relationship
#  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       
#1 A          B          lowers      
#2 B          C          lowers      
#3 A          D          lowers      
#4 D          E          raises      
#5 E          C          raises
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(StartValue = c("A", "A"), MiddleValue = c("B", 
"D, E"), FinalValue = c("C", "C"), Relationship = c("lowers, lowers", 
"lowers, raises, raises")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer my question - I really appreciate it. However, the output you got is not the one I was looking for - if you look at the StartValues you would see. Any further advice?

Comment: @RoadToFreedom Sorry, I didn't look at the 'StartValue' column.  Now, I updated.  Please check the output now